# mysql join incorrect results

Tags: mysql

Each childrow has a parentid and position. For childrows with the same position there is one row where `start='1'`.

What i'm trying to do is return the pending rows with their start row.

The results that should be shown are; start(owen) pending(dave,paul).  This is because they have the same position.  Here is the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e54/1

```
  id |  name | parentid|  position|  start  |  pending |
   1 |  mike |    0    |    0     |    0    |     0    |
   2 |  dave |    1    |    1     |    0    |     1    | 
   3 |  paul |    1    |    1     |    0    |     1    |
   4 |  john |    1    |    2     |    1    |     0    |
   5 |  bret |    1    |    2     |    0    |     0    |
   6 |  owen |    1    |    1     |    1    |     0    |
   7 |  rick |    1    |    3     |    1    |     0    |
   8 |  jaye |    1    |    3     |    0    |     0    |



    $getquery = mysql_query("select child.*
from `mytable` child inner join `mytable` parent 
on parent.id=child.parentid
inner join `mytable` child2 on child.parentid=child2.parentid
and child2.pending='1'
where child.start='1' ORDER BY child.id DESC");



while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)) {

 $name = $row['name'];

echo "<p>Name: $name </p>";

}
```

Comment: Your query does not use `chid2` for output. Join with the parent eliminates the root entry, so you may want to skip it altogether.

Comment: oh i see.. How would i get desired results?  The pending rows and their start rows?

Comment: Why would only owen, dave and paul be shown? And not all rows?

Comment: dave,paul and owen have the same position.  Owen is the start row and dave/paul are pending rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from `mytable` order by position, pending
```

You can add a `where position=1` clause if that's the only position of interest.